# Why document.getElementById is returning null?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a submit form dynamically. But on click of the submit button I am getting error on following line.

```
var name = document.getElementById("form").value;
```

Following is the the complete code.

#### Script

```
function createPage() {
    function form() {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute('method', "post");
        form.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi, my name is "));

        function input() {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute('type', "text");
            input.setAttribute('name', "name");
            return input;
        }

        form.appendChild(input());

        function button() {
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Submit"));

            function submit() {
                var name = document.getElementById("form").value;
                alert("My name is " + name);
            }

            button.onclick = submit;
            return button;
        }

        form.appendChild(button());
        return form;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form());
}
```

#### HTML

```
<body onload="createPage()"></body>
```

Comment: I don't see any code giving an element the id "form", so which element did you expect to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

You did not set an ID to the `<form>` element. Just try with:

```
form.setAttribute('id', 'form');
```

Or change the method of accessing this element to:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")  // it returns an array of elements
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the id of the form element you have created.

So, after setting the method attribute, simply add the form id as

```
form.setAttribute('id', "form");
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you haven't set the form id. `createElement()` doesn't set the id of the field to the name of the element itself.

`document.createElement("form");` creates `<form></form>`. As you can see, no id, you have to set it manually.

But you really do not want to access the value of the form, but the one of the input field.

So, first of all, set an id to the input field: `input.setAttribute('id', 'name');`

Then, access that id to get the value:

`var name = document.getElementById("name").value;`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function createPage() {
                function form() {
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute('method', "post");
                    form.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi, my name is "));
                    function input() {
                        var input = document.createElement("input");
                        input.setAttribute('id', 'name');
                        input.setAttribute('type', "text");
                        input.setAttribute('name', "name");
                        return input;
                    }
                    form.appendChild(input());
                    function button() {
                        var button = document.createElement("button");
                        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Submit"));
                        function submit() {
                            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                            alert("My name is " + name);
                        }
                        button.onclick = submit;
                        return button;
                    }
                    form.appendChild(button());
                    return form;
                }
                document.body.appendChild(form());
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="createPage()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to resolve this,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createPage() {
            function form() {
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute('method', "post");
                form.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi, my name is "));
        var input;                    
    function input() {
                    input = document.createElement("input");
                    input.setAttribute('type', "text");
                    input.setAttribute('name', "name");
                    return input;
                }
                form.appendChild(input());
                function button() {
                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Submit"));
                    function submit() {
                        var name = input.value;
                alert("My name is " + name);
                    }
                    button.onclick = submit;
                    return button;
                }
                form.appendChild(button());
                return form;
            }
            document.body.appendChild(form());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="createPage()">
</body>
```